# Why is this check throwing an error, even if I check whether it’s undefined beforehand?

Tags: javascript, json

I passed in a series of JSON objects with an AJAX call. Some of the data sets include the field `C` and some do not. When I include the following code, it crashes. I have tried `undefined` and `null`. Both crash.

```
if (myJsonObjects[i].C == undefined) {
  // …
}
```

Comment: This line should not be the reason for the browser to crash, assuming `myJsonObjects[i]` is an object. I think you have to post more of your code.

Comment: if(myJsonObjects[i].C == "undefined" ){ - to check for "undefined" dont forget to make a string out of undefined

Comment: @philipp: Only together with `typeof`.

Comment: How does it "crash"? What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say crash I presume you mean `TypeError: cannot read property of undefined value`

The reason it crashes is because in the line

`if(myJsonObjects[i].C == undefined){`

We actually have `myJSONObject[i] === undefined`

So really you need to check your array bounds or make sure your array is not sparse

Answer (score 2):

```
if(myJsonObjects[i].C == undefined){
```

is the similar as

```
if(myJsonObjects[i] && myJsonObjects[i].C){
```

but with mine line, you check is `myJsonObjects[i]` and `myJsonObjects[i].c` are null or undefined.

The caveat being if `myJsonObjects[i].c` holds `false, "", 0, NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (typeof myJsonObjects[i].C == 'undefined') {}
```

Comment: @Raynos Knock off the mysterious comments and offer something constructive.

Comment: I agree with @Raynos, this is exactly the same code functionality-wise as in the OP and the crash reason is not accounted for at all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could test the waters a little before jumping right in:

```
if( i in myJsonObjects && myJsonObjects[i] && !( "C" in myJsonObjects[i] ) ) { }
```

However your original code should not crash and shouldn't throw error either if `myJsonObjects[i]` is defined and is not null

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if ('C' in myJsonObjects[i]) { do_your_magic() }
```